# Spring websocket example - error - Are you running in a Servlet container that supports J SR-356?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-websocket

I am trying to run the Spring 4 example given @ https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket. When I try to connect to socket, it throws me following exception. As per the example you need tomcat 7.0.50 and I checked the executable jar which has right version of tomcat. Any pointer would be helpful.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer'   ServletContext attribute. Are you running in a Servlet container that supports JSR-356?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have `tomcat7-websocket.jar` and `websocket-api.jar` bundled in your executable jar - perhaps you're just getting vanilla tomcat without the extra websocket bits.

Comment: thx Paul. I dont see both of these jars in executable. Its has tomcat-embed-core-7.0.50.jar, tomcat-embed-jasper-7.0.50.jar, spring-websocket-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar etc.

Comment: The class you're missing 'javax.websocket.server.ServerContainer' lives in websocket-api.jar which you can get from the standard tomcat download.

Comment: I am able to solve this using tomcat7:run which forced maven to download right version of tomcat. Thx Paul.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error message in another use case: I deactivated auto configuration and added `WebSocketConfig` manually to the configuration. Then I got the abovementioned error message.

Fixing the problem was easy: just adding `WebSocketAutoConfiguration` to the configuration.

Comment: How do I do that? Currently  I have xml web socket configuration and getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an ancient thread but I ran into this error and resolved it in modern times by adding `implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat")` explicitly to my project.