# Archive for required library tomcat-embed-websocket in project cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I created a new Spring project using the Initialzr https://start.spring.io/ using the settings:

```
Group: com.renielcanlas
Artifact: SpringDemo
```

with dependencies, **web**, **actuator**, and **devtools** then

- I downloaded the package
- unzip to my workspace
- Import to eclipse as Maven Project
- Build Project

then I received an error

> Archive for required library: 'C:/Users/[**PCNAME**]/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.32/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar' in project 'SpringDemo' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file    SpringDemo      Build path  Build Path Problem

I tried the following:

- Download a fresh copy of the jar file from MavenRepository
- Replace the given jar file (in error) with new one
- Re-build
- RightClick>>Maven>>UpdateProject from eclipse

and still not working. It still gives the same error.

 I already checked the following questions:
[Unable to resolve Eclipse "Archive for required library..." issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28911862/unable-to-resolve-eclipse-archive-for-required-library-issue)

[Spring websocket in embedded tomcat 8.0.21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39207474/spring-websocket-in-embedded-tomcat-8-0-21)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Action

> Replace the given jar file (in error) with new one

is not assured every dependencies will work ok.

Your dependencies at your Manven local are corrupted/error. You need delete old/error dependencies, by delete action in file manager, or go to your directory where has `pom.xml`, release command

```
mvn dependency:purge-local-repository
```

then close IDE, re-run Maven again.

Comment: did this one, successfully built the project, but when I run the Applicaiton starter, I received the error:
<br><br>
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to read Class-Path attribute from manifest of jar file:/C:/Users/[pcname]/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.32/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.32.jar`

Comment: delete everything in your Maven local repository